# How can I keep the context of 'this' in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have something like this:

```
var Something = function(){
  this.render = function(){};
  $(window).resize(function(){
    this.render();
  });
}
```

The trouble is that inside the anonymous function 'this' refers to the window object. I know I could do something like:

```
var Something = function(){
  this.render = function(){};
  var tempThis = this;
  $(window).resize(function(){
    tempThis.render();
  });
}
```

but is there a better way? This doesn't look very elegant.

Comment: You should put a "var" before the "tempThis = this" to ensure proper scope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution you found is the the one most people use. The common convention is to call your tempThis variable "that."

```
var Something = function(){
  this.render = function(){};
  var that = this;
  $(window).resize(function(){
    that.render();
  });
};
```

Comment: well having a convention makes it look more elegant :) I like "that".

Comment: +1 for that = this -> This is the most elegant method that I ever found for this question.

Comment: Props to Douglas Crockford for popularizing -- if not inventing -- that convention. :-) http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: Please add a "var" before "that" in order to not polute the global scope with your variable. Another convention is to call this variable "self".

Comment: I used to use "self" until I noticed that there's a global variable named "self" in browsers sometimes that refers to the global object. If you typo something, your this becomes the global object again, and no error is thrown, and it's harder to track down because it *looks* like you did the right thing, but it's doing the wrong thing anyway!

Answer (score 2):

That looks like your best option, I don't think there's a better way. (someone correct my if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 1):

FYI the ability to control this is coming in the [next version of JQuery](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/05/12/jquery-edge-bind-with-a-different-this)

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing it this way in many tight situations. It doesn't look elegant, but it never fails. Actually thats javascript closures in action.

jrh

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what I do. It's not specific to jQuery, either.

```
var Construct = function() {
    var self = this; //preserve scope

    this.materials = 2000;

    this.build = function(){
        self.materials -= 100;
    };
};
```

Remember to use the var keyword in front of your new scope variable. Otherwise, you're creating a new global variable. As a local variable, it will still be accessible inside the inner function via a closure.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, to keep variables at a minimum would be to use the Function.prototype.bind() method.

```
var Something = function(){
  this.render = function(){};
  $(window).resize( this.render.bind( this ) );
}
```

The problem with this method that may cause future complications, which means you should choose to use it sparingly, is when you need to invoke `$(this)` to grab the element. So, I might suggest that it would be worthwhile to use `Function.prototype.bind()` in your resize method, but it would not be a good solution to use it in a click function that you might need to target the clicked element directly.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kd7yk/1/) for a working example.

See the [Mozilla Documentation on Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more information

The other methods are usable, but creating a variable to maintain the context of this is the undesired effect according to your question.