# Scoping "this" in Javascript (and jQuery.extend)

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Sorry if this has been answered, but I couldn't turn up a search for it... a difficult thing to search for, I think!

Say I have this:

```
var MyPrototype = function() { this.init(); }
$.extend(MyPrototype.prototype, {
    a: 5,
    init: function() {
        var thing = new SomeOtherClass();
        thing.meth = this.meth;
        // thing.meth() is called somewhere within thing;
    },
    meth: function() {
        alert(this.a);
    }
}
```

Basically, I am dealing with another class which uses its own methods as callbacks, e.g. I am expected to override them with my own functionality. But I need to retain the proper scope of `this` while doing it (the only thing I care about from `SomeOtherClass` is what's passed to the callback; nothing in the state).

As you might imagine, this doesn't work because `thing` has no `a` property! I am not familiar enough with the intricacies of Javascript scoping to know how to make `this` refer to what I want, though!

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520019/controlling-the-value-of-this-in-a-jquery-event ...and also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043556/how-can-i-keep-the-context-of-this-in-jquery ...and really, most of the questions in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this+javascript (this is an extremely common point of confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining two other answers here, so that you don't have to rewrite your meth function, I'd do this:

```
    var me = this;
    thing.meth = function() {
        MyPrototype.meth.apply(me, arguments);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't control how it's called you could try this:

```
var MyPrototype = function() { this.init(); }
$.extend(MyPrototype.prototype, {
    a: 5,
    init: function() {
        var thing = new SomeOtherClass();

        // Create an aliad for this
        var that = this;
        thing.meth = function() {
            // You can always access the object using it's "that" alias
            alert(that.a);
        };
    }
}
```

Or...

```
var MyPrototype = function() { this.init(); }
$.extend(MyPrototype.prototype, {
    a: 5,
    init: function() {
        var thing = new SomeOtherClass();

        // Create an aliad for this
        var that = this;
        thing.meth = function() {
            // You can always access the object using it's "that" alias
            that.meth();
        };
    },
    meth: {
        alert(this.a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the start of your code sample, add this line:

```
var self = this;
```

Then replace all uses of 'this' in your code with 'self'.

(I think a bunch of the answers to this are saying more or less the same thing.)

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
thing.meth.call(this);
```

or

```
thing.meth.apply(this);
```

(The only difference is in how arguments are passed, which doesn't matter in this case.)

Comment: Unfortunately, as they are callbacks initiated from `SomeOtherClass`, I don't actually control how they are called.

Comment: In that case, you just need to wrap the callback in a closure so the value of "this" is carried along with the function reference.  *edsoverflow* already posted an example.

Answer (score -1):

Could you do something like this?

```
var MyPrototype = function() { this.init(); }
$.extend(MyPrototype.prototype, {
    a: 5,
    init: function() {
        var thing = new SomeOtherClass();
        var self = this;
        thing.meth = function(){this.meth.apply(self)};
        // thing.meth() is called somewhere within thing;
    },
    meth: function() {
        alert(this.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "this" within the "helper" method that calls "meth" still has the same problem that it originally had.

Comment: Changed it to use self.  Works ok for me now.