# How can jQuery plugin options become undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-mobile

I'm using a plugin structure like this:

```
(function( $, window) { 
    $.widget("mobile.multiview",$.mobile.widget, {
        options: {  
           switchable: false,           
           },
        create: function() {
           var self = this;
           // returns false
           console.log(self.options.switchable)
           },
        bindings: function() {
           $(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
              var self = this,
                  $link = self.options.switchable;
              // this is undefined, when the event fires - function fails
              console.log( $link )  
              });
           }
        }) 
     }) (jQuery,this);
```

I don't understand, how the options can become *undefined*. I have plenty of options and they are all undefined if I console them within the pagebeforechange event.

They seem to work everywhere else, so I'm clueless as to why they are failing here. Any idea that could lead me in the right directon?

Comment: is it me? or do i see that your code has some missing close brackets?

Comment: then check the code again. [there ***are*** missing closing brackets](http://jsfiddle.net/E2SZ7/)

Comment: thx. I hope I have them all now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` will be the document instead of the widget, your scope is different.

Just re-read your code `$(document).on(... var self = this`. In the `create` method assign `this` to a variable that will be available elsewhere.

Some info on how to keep the context here:

[How can I keep the context of 'this' in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043556/how-can-i-keep-the-context-of-this-in-jquery)

To fix this you can also just move the self declaration out of the closure:

```
    bindings: function() {
       var self = this;
       $(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
          var $link = self.options.switchable;
          console.log( $link ); 
       });
    }
```

Comment: hm. so how can I change the scrope to the widget to access the option value?

Comment: OH. I see. Thanks for pointing that out. This & That is also nice!

Comment: @frequent Updated with an easy fix

Answer (score 1):

The plugin template i use for all my jQuery plugins is this:

```
(function($){

$.fn.widget = function(options){
   var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.widget.defaults, options);

return this.each(function(){
   //get a reference to the DOM element.
   var obj = $(this);
   //because you extended your options into your defaults, you can use them like this
   var isSwitchable = opts.switchable; 
};
};
//private function
function sayHello(name){
   alert(name);
};
//public functions
$.fn.widget.sayHello = function(name){
   alert("hello" + name);
};
//default settings
$.fn.widget.defaults = {
    switchable: false
};
})(jQuery);
```

You can use your options inside your plugin by calling the opts variable.